# Salesforce .Enterprise WSDL in .net integration (Generate .Net stub code from salesforce enterprise WSDL)

Tags: salesforce

I created Enterprise WSDL from SFDC and saved it on local machine.
When I add a web reference in VS 2008 it just add  a reference to wsdl it does not generate a stub code ( code class) I also tried by using 'Add Service Reference' and 'Add Service Reference'--> Advanced --> Add Web Reference.

Can you please comment on this, what I am missing and How I can generate a C# code from Enterprise WSDL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question are not clear enought. After adding a web reference, u should be abe to call it just by typing the namespace/reference. Something like var service = new EnterpriseWSDL.SforceService(); If u are having trouble to add the web reference to the project, try to put the .wsdl on c:\inetpub\wwwroot besides the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

please put your local wsdl service physical path

like as

Add Service Reference'--> Advanced --> Add Web Reference-->**C:\ramki\test.wsdl**